# Server-side network printing in java / grails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, grails, printing, network-programming

I am java / grails developer working on redesigning a software system.

One of the requirements is to have a sever-side application send data to various network printers to print text data.

I searched the web for info on java network printing, and came up short
I looked into Java Print Service API, java.awt.print, javax.print and did not find anything on connecting to network printers.

Is what I am trying to do possible or favorable. The lack of findings leads me to believe that sever-side software does not interact with network printers directly.

If it can be done, please point me to some resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network printers are typically treated no differently from locally connected printers; they are set up in the OS first and this makes them available to the Java Print Service.

If you need to print directly to a POS printer, they usually have their own binary protocol that you can use over TCP/UDP. Epson has the ESC/POS system, for example.

Depending on the print server, you may be able to send PostScript straight to the printer via CUPS/LRP/LPD/IPP. See http://www.cups4j.org and http://lpdspooler.sourceforge.net.

Comment: Thank you for answering. That is my issue, I don't want the printers to be  set up in the OS. There are many printers located at various locations (50+ and growing). Currently these printers are accompanied by a PC. This PC handles the printing to the printer. It done with ajax calls to javascript code running on the pc to use the browser to print. I want to remove this pc and have my server-side application send data directly to the printers over the network by ip. Any tips thanks

Comment: I already told you how to do that. See CUPS/LRP/LPD/IPP; Java can communicate with them directly, via the libraries I linked in my answer.

Comment: You are new here, so I will cut you some slack, but you should mark your question as answered and my response as useful. When people are going out of their way to help you, the least you can do is actually read their responses properly and follow etiquette. Not doing so may get you flagged.

Comment: I was just explaining my situation in more detail and i can't vote answers yet as i am a new user