# server-side network printing java / grails

Tags: java, networking, jakarta-ee, grails, printing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server-side network printing in java / grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368272/server-side-network-printing-in-java-grails)

I am Java/grails developer working on redesigning a software system.

One of the requirements is to have a sever-side application send data to various network printers to print text data

I searched the web for info on java network printing, and came up short. Then I looked into Java Print Service API, java.awt.print, javax.print and did not find anything on connecting to network printers

Is what I'm trying to do possible or favorable? The lack of findings leads me to believe that sever-side software does not interact with network printers directly.

Also, can this be  done at all? If so please point me to some resources

Thank you and have a nice day